# Generate a decodable string from a set of variables

Tags: python, string, hash, decode, encode

I have a code which have a number of configuration variables (of various types). For each set of configurations, I am generating a file. I want to name this file based on the configuration I used to generate the file. However, since I have about 20 configurations, the filename becomes too large if I just use the configuration values as strings and concatenate into a filename.

Is there a way to generate a string from a set of variables which I can later decode into the original variable values (so that I can find out the configurations I used for the file)? **Filename can be gibberish and long (as long as it can be used as a filename in linux)**

i.e. I need something like this

```
conf1 = 10
conf2 = (20,2)
conf3 = "some string"
conf4 = {'c1': 10, 'c2': None}

filename = get_filename(conf1, conf2, conf3, conf4)  # Encode function
conf1_, conf2_, conf3_, conf4_ = str2conf(filename)  # Decode function
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did if anyone come across a similar problem. Here I have only `int`, `float` and `bool` configs given in a dictionary

```
def encode_args(*, r:float, l:float, s:float, c:int, f:int, n:int, L:int, H:int, p:float, C:int, e:bool) -> str:
    return f"r{int(r/1000)}l{int(l*1000)}s{int(s*1000)}c{c}f{f}n{n}" \
           f"L{L}H{H}p{int(p*100)}C{C}e{1 if e else 0}"

import re

def decode_str(string) -> dict:
    r, l, s, c, f, n, L, H, p, C, e = \
        re.search(r'r(\d+)l(\d+)s(\d+)c(\d+)f(\d+)n(\d+)L(\d+)H(\d+)p(\d+)C(\d+)e(\d)', string).groups()
    r, l, s, c, f, n, L, H, p, C, e = map(int, [r, l, s, c, f, n, L, H, p, C, e])
    r *= 1000
    l /= 1000
    s /= 1000
    p /= 100
    e = e == 1
    return dict(r=r, l=l, s=s, c=c, f=f, n=n, L=L, H0=H, p=p, C=C, e=e)
```

Answer (score -1):

If the number of possible configurations are fixed at 20, you could encode each with a letter of the alphabet (i.e.  config1 = 'A', config2= 'B', ....) Then name your file based on the up to 20 letters denoting the configurations used to create the file.

The encoding could be encapsulated in a dictionary by either Encoded Char: config, or vice versa.

Here is what I mean using your example:

```
conf1 = 10
conf2 = (20, 2)
conf3 = "some string"
conf4 = [4,5,6]
nam_dict = {conf1:'A', conf2:'B', conf2:"C", conf4:'D'}
filename=get_filename(conf1, conf2, conf3, conf4)

def get_filename(*cnfigs):
    fs = 'f'
    for k in cnfigs:
       fs += nam_dict[k]
    return fs
```

Comment: I don't fully understand your answer. Yes the number of configurations are fixed but the values those configurations can have vary in a large range. How do you propose to generate a filename from 'A'-`10.123`, 'B'-`{'c1': 10, 'c2': None}` ?

Comment: As in your specified example: